# I am not able to call a query to my database. I am assuming it is not properly connected

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am not sure I understand the labels properly. I get this error **"blogs:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"**. I've attached a picture of my MySQL home screen.

```
import * as mysql from 'mysql';
import Blogs from './blogs';
export const Connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '127.0.0.1', //I don't if this is what I am Supposed to put here
  port: 3306,
  user: 'suggesteventuser',
  password: 'thisfakepassword',
  database: 'Recomend an Adventure',
});

export const Query = (query: string, values?: Array<string | number>) => {
  return new Promise<Array<any>>((resolve, reject) => {
    Connection.query(query, values, (err, results) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(results);
    });
  });
};

export default {
  Blogs,
};
// When I try to go to this route I get this error message
router.get('/api/blogs', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.json(await db.Blogs.all());
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

## Error message:

> blogs:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: is suppose this are two different files. and you shouldn't await inside response like that and i reckon you need to stringify the response object before sending  `try { const data = await db.Blogs.all()
    res.json(JSON.stringify(data))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }`

Comment: I am still getting an internal server error

Comment: becasue something is breaking in your try block and your sending  response 500 in catch block. try to debug the code in try block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your database is the name of the folder in your project *usually mydatabase*

> If you match up the code to the image you should be able to replicate a proper
> connection to your database this was surprisingly hard to find so I hope this helps!

```sql
mysql:{
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'suggesteventu...',
        password: 'yourpassword
        database: 'mydatabase',
    }
```

[image: MySql Work Bench]